# How to run android sencha application in android emulator

Tags: android, extjs, android-emulator, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I saw questions like this in stackoverflow but, answers not satisfied me. My main problem is i have to check how my android sencha application running at various version of android mobiles.

From starting onwards i tested the application in android 2.3.4 mobile, now i almost finished my application so i want to test my application in all the version android, so i trying to run  my application in android emulator.

I ran the application but only got error, so i searched for how to run android sencha application in emulator, then i got this link [Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for Android](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android), i tried to follow guide in that link, i installed SenchaSDKTools 2.0 and Sencha Cmd.

and tried to run

```
sencha package run android.json
```

this what i got

```
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[ERR]       stbuild is not yet supported on linux
```

I am using ubuntu 12.4.

Comment: check the solution posted below. Let me know if you have still issues. Thanks.

Comment: I have already done exactly same. other android applications with phonegap(without sencha-touch) running good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run `sencha application` on `Android`, you required `cordova` integration which will provide a bridge between `sencha` and `android`.

I have already posted **details steps** for such things.

**Please see this link.**

[Integrate Phonegap/Cordova with Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854393/556975)

Follow those **steps** and you are **done**.

Just consider ***5th step*** there, you need to place **whole your sencha app code** into `assets/www` **folder** and make sure `index.html` is in the **root(www) folder**.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already done exactly same. other android  applications with phonegap(without sencha-touch) running good.

Comment: @Viswa make sure with your `cordova js` is loading before all other `sencha js`.

Comment: Thanks, i changed now, but i still got errors (log msg ) **'Required permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE is unknown to PackageManager' 'If you're running in an emulator, you need to install the appropriate image through the Android SDK and AVM manager. See http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/ for further details.'**

Comment: @Viswa what errors you are getting? please post that too. That will be easy to find out exact what is creating problem there.

Comment: ya, i just did, see the above comment.

Comment: @Viswa are you dealing with `push notification` in your application?

Comment: what about this guide: (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android-section-2 )

Comment: yes my application uses push notification and i made it successful.

Comment: for the information, my application running good in android 2.3.4 mobile