# Set up Phonegap with eclipse

Tags: android, html, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I went through some documentation regarding Phonegap. Coming from an Android background, I wanted to try out phonegap so that I could develop multiple-platform apps relatively fast, however I am uncertain on a specific point. Is it possible to install phonegap on eclipse and code a multiple-platform app from there? Or do I have to stay installing xcode, visual basic etc and coding for every one?

Can someone kindly indicate what the best practice is in this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this link :

[Integrate Phonegap with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854393/556975)

That will show you step by step process.

> if you want to use the same code for multiple platform then you have
>   to upload the code which is under `www` folder to [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) site.
>   They will provide you multiple builds directly. Or if you proceed
>   separately like Android above then you have to generate separate
>   builds with separate ides available like eclipse for Android and xcode
>   for iphone.

Thanks.

Comment: but the code I generate from that IDE, how can I use it for multiple platforms? Or will it only work on Android? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you will download PhoneGap that will be included with an example just import that example & run that example in eclipse & go through all the files available in that Project . So that you will understand that which files you have to put where & how .