# Can't intslall phonegap with ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I just checked here

[PhoneGap not running in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852980/phonegap-not-running-in-android/13854393#13854393)

What I did are as follows

1. I copied cordova-2.9.0.jar file from phonegap inside libs folder though it dont show there! dont know why
2. Then made www folder under assets and added cordova-2.9.0.js file there
3. Copy xml folder came with cordova source into res folder
4. Then I replaced `mainactivity.java` with this code

   ```
   package com.cordovatest;

   import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

   import android.os.Bundle;

   public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);        
           super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",1000);
       }
   }
   ```

   But I see so many errors see screenshot

   http://gyazo.com/4e1fa15d0f5926d7a6ff6524645b0952
   5.Added index.html file into assets/www folder
5. Then I added this code to my `androidmanifest.xml`

   http://gyazo.com/8e7b079ae928d53a87a5328c37b89ae1

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot link did not work, can you please check to see if that's the right URL? Also did you first use the `/bin/create/` script to make a sample app and THEN do these steps? Also, I'm not seeing the step where you set the Android Target API level; you need to right click on the project, click properties, then Android,  then make sure that the highest Android version has been checked.

Comment: right now i see no errors i guess phonegap is installed properly.. is there a way to test this ?